# Help with drawing a unit circle & lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a unit circle with labelled coordinates of points on it as well as  lines that intersect the circle like this:

[image]

The code that I pasted below does part of the job. But I want

1. coordinates that are larger,
2. the lines, and
3. the slopes of the lines labelled, ideally without the lines intersecting the labels.

I would greatly appreciate help.

---

```
% Unit circle % Author: Supreme Aryal
% A unit circle with cosine and sine values for some
% common angles.

\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} %%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}% %%%>

\begin{comment} :Title: Unit circle

A unit circle with cosine and sine values for some common angles.

\end{comment}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry} \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5.3,cap=round,>=latex]
        % draw the coordinates
        \draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white] {$y$};

        % draw the unit circle
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);

        \foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
                % lines from center to point
                % dots at each point
                \filldraw[black] (\x:1cm) circle(0.4pt);
                % draw each angle in degrees
        }


        \foreach \x/\xtext/\y in {
            % the coordinates for the first quadrant
            30/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            45/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            60/\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the second quadrant
            150/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/\frac{1}{2},
            135/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            120/-\frac{1}{2}/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the third quadrant
            210/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            225/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            240/-\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},
            % the coordinates for the fourth quadrant
            330/\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}/-\frac{1}{2},
            315/\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},
            300/\frac{1}{2}/-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}
                \draw (\x:1.45cm) node[fill=white] {$\left(\xtext,\y\right)$};

        % draw the horizontal and vertical coordinates
        % the placement is better this way
        \draw (-1.25cm,0cm) node[above=1pt] {$(-1,0)$}
              (1.25cm,0cm)  node[above=1pt] {$(1,0)$}
              (0cm,-1.25cm) node[fill=white] {$(0,-1)$}
              (0cm,1.25cm)  node[fill=white] {$(0,1)$};
    \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe a little clean up would be beneficial

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cap=round,>=latex,every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
        \draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white]{$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
% Source of rays
\coordinate (s) at (-1cm,0);
\node[above left] at (-1cm,0) {$(-1,0)$};
\foreach \x in {2,1,0.5,0.333333,-0.25,-1}{
\draw[orange] (s)--++({atan2(1,\x)}:2) node[black,right] {$m=\pgfmathprintnumber[frac]{\x}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the fractions that are placed via `fpu` library are really, I mean really, sensitive to the number input. If you remove a few `3`s from `0.333333` you'll probably understand what I'm warning for :)

Also if you want to scale up, the node shapes needs the key `transform shape` option to follow the current transformation. So it's maybe better to scale the nodes independently as I did via `every node/.style={...}`.

---

For Luigi's question in the comments, we can simply use the half angle relation to get where it crosses the circle and then extend a fix amount from that point such that the extensions are always the same length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cap=round,>=latex,every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
        \draw[->] (-1.5cm,0cm) -- (1.5cm,0cm) node[right,fill=white]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0cm,-1.5cm) -- (0cm,1.5cm) node[above,fill=white]{$y$};
        \draw[thick] (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm);
% Source of rays
\coordinate (s) at (-1cm,0);
\node[above left] at (-1cm,0) {$(-1,0)$};
\foreach \x in {2,1,0.5,0.333333,-0.25,-1}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\myhalfangle{2*atan2(1,\x)}
\draw[orange] (s)-- ({cos(\myhalfangle)},{sin(\myhalfangle)}) 
-- ++(0.5*\myhalfangle:1.2cm) node[black,right] {$m=\pgfmathprintnumber[frac]{\x}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Though why doesn't the m = 2 line go through the point (0, 1)...?

Comment: @anonymous12345 It was wrong. Now corrected.

Comment: @percusse, what if the length of the arrows varied in such a way that the arrow tips protruded from the circle by the same length?

Comment: @Luigi See the second example :)

Comment: +1 @percusse, pardon! I saw it yesterday (and upvoted) but didn't reply. I don't know which is better. I thought it would have been neater, but due to the m=2 line, they are all too long. Anyway, I did it so:`\pgfmathparse{sqrt(2+2*cos(2*atan2(1,\x)))+0.2}` in your original code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@percusse's answer is great (+1 of course), but when it comes to drawing pictures that use axis I would definitely consider [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots). The output is very similar

[image]

but the construction is slightly different

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
                    axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
                    axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
                    axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
                    xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
                    ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
                    }}


% set the arrows as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis equal,
            xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
            ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
            xtick={-10},
            ytick={-10},
            ]
    \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
    \node  at (axis cs:-1,0)[anchor=south east]{$(-1,0)$};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,0.5,0.333333,-0.25,-1}{
        \pgfmathparse{2*cos(atan2(1,#1))-1}
        \addplot[red,->] expression[domain=-1:{\pgfmathresult}]{#1*x+#1}node[black,right] {$m=\pgfmathprintnumber[frac]{#1}$};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I like this approach because of the global settings for the axis. With a little work in the preamble, you can then spice up the picture (using globally defined settings), for example

```
% framing
\pgfplotsset{framed/.style={axis background/.style ={draw=blue,fill=yellow!20,rounded corners=3ex}}}
```

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis equal,
            xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
            ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
            xtick={-10},
            ytick={-10},
            minor xtick={-1.5,-1,...,1.5},
            minor ytick={-1.5,-1,...,1.5},
            framed,
            grid=both,
            ]
    \addplot [domain=0:2*pi,samples=50] ({cos(deg(x))},{sin(deg(x))});
    \node  at (axis cs:-1,0)[anchor=south east]{$(-1,0)$};
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,0.5,0.333333,-0.25,-1}{
        \pgfmathparse{2*cos(atan2(1,#1))-1}
        \addplot[red,->] expression[domain=-1:{\pgfmathresult}]{#1*x+#1}node[black,right] {$m=\pgfmathprintnumber[frac]{#1}$};
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Great use of `pgfplots` +1.

Comment: @cmhughes, why the four arrows for the axes? And what if the length of the arrows varied in such a way that the arrow tips protruded from the circle by the same length? Hint: `\pgfmathparse{cos(2*atan2(1,#1))+0.15*cos(atan2(1,#1))}`. P.S. I always set `samples=2` for straight lines.

Comment: @Luigi I'm British, but currently live in America- the Americans put arrows on their axis